# Foreach com table

Tags: php, css3, codeigniter, api

Estou criando um site que tem como objetivo mostrar os jogos que estão acontecendo no mundo em tempo real. Estou tentando fazer um for para as linhas das tabelas serem criadas "sozinhas" de acordo com o tanto de jogos que terá no momento que vir da API, estou usando a API do bet365.
Tentativa que fiz:

```
 <?php
  for(i=0;i<=$transaction['results'];i++){
  echo "<th></th>";
  }
 ?>
```

Segue foto com o modelo do layout:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: Eu queria que fosse intercaladas as cores também como mostra na foto.

Para exibir os resultados estou usando o seguinte código:

```
   foreach ($transaction['results'] as $element) {

                echo $element['league']['name'].PHP_EOL;
                echo $element['home']['name'].PHP_EOL;
                echo $element['away']['name'].PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Modelo do JSON que vem da API

```
  {
   "success": 1,
   "pager": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 1000,
    "total": 4
     },
     "results": [
     {
     "id": "77564080",
    "time": "1543528800",
    "time_status": "1",
    "league": {
        "id": "3024",
        "name": "Copa Libertadores - Feminino"
    },
    "home": {
        "id": "9105",
        "name": "EC Iranduba - Feminino"
    },
    "away": {
        "id": "170148",
        "name": "Atlético Huila - Feminino"
    },
    "ss": "1-0",
    "our_event_id": "1093051"
},
```

Comment: Você pretende fazer tudo isso via PHP? Pois acredito que o caminho ideal seria realizar toda a tratativa relacionada a organização da tabela com Javascript, utilizar o PHP somente para captar os dados da API e enviar para as Views no CI. O próprio CI já induz essa estrutura.

Comment: Adicionei o modelo que como vem os códigos da API, Então sim eu estava pensando em fazer tudo em PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi o que tu não ta conseguindo fazer, fiz um exemplo rápido parecido com o que tu mostro, [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VHiQ.jpg) uma imagem mostrando o resultado.
Tu vai ter que alterar o css pra ficar da forma que tu que mas a base já ta feita, além disso ajustar o nome das colunas e imprimir as váriaveis certas. Se tiver dúvidas com tables pode ver [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Coluna 1</th>
        <th>Coluna 2</th>
        <th>Coluna 3</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($json['results'] as $key => $element) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $element['league']['name'].'<br>'.$element['home']['name'].' X '.$element['away']['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $element['ss']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '00:00'; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Obrigada! fajuchem +1